# Issue downloading an image from URL obtained from SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am in the process of creating an Android application in Android Studio. I have run into a bit of a snag along the way. I am using a pretty standard ListView that can have items added and removed - that bit is working perfectly. In order to store the data on the users phone (and because I do not have my own server yet) I have opted to store the data on the user's phone.

In order to store the data for the application I have created an SQLite database using the following tutorial but changing some column names and adding columns to suit my needs http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/.

One of the columns I have created contains a URL to a movie poster image. My object class downloads this image and sets it as a Drawable - this bit is also working perfectly. I am able to successfully store the URL in the database and it pulls out correctly when the application is reloaded. However, when I reload the application the items previously in the ListView do not download the image even though the correct URL is being passed to the Object class. Please help me see where I have gone wrong..code below. Thanks ahead of time!

Database Helper (where I CRUD the SQLite database)

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
//database version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
//database name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "moviesManager";
//table name
private static final String TABLE_MOVIES = "movies";
//table column names
private static final String KEY_ID = "idSTRING";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "Title";
private static final String KEY_YEAR = "Year";
private static final String KEY_RATING = "Rating";
private static final String KEY_POSTER = "URL";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}

//creating tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_MOVIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MOVIES + "("
            + KEY_ID + "STRING PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_YEAR + " TEXT," + KEY_RATING + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_POSTER + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_MOVIES_TABLE);
}

//upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MOVIES);
    //create table again
    onCreate(db);
}

//CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
//add new movie
void addMovie(Movie movie){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, movie.getId());
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, movie.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_YEAR, movie.getYear());
    values.put(KEY_RATING, movie.getRating());
    values.put(KEY_POSTER, movie.getImgUrl());
    //Log.e("poster:", values.get(KEY_POSTER).toString());

    //Inserting row
    db.insert(TABLE_MOVIES, movie.getId(), values);
    //Log.e("Poster in DB: ",getMovie(movie.getId()).getImgUrl());
    db.close(); //closing database connection
}

public List<Movie> getAllMovies(){
    List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MOVIES;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    //looping through all rows and adding to list
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do{
            Movie movie = new Movie();
            movie.setId(cursor.getString(0));
            movie.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            movie.setYear(cursor.getString(2));
            movie.setRating(cursor.getString(3));
            movie.setPoster(cursor.getString(4));
            movieList.add(movie);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    //cursor.close();
    return movieList;
}
  ...
}
```

From MainActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

     ...

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    movies = db.getAllMovies();
    mAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this, movies);
    lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    ...
}
```

From Movie class:

```
...
public void setPoster(String imgUrl) {
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    this.poster = LoadImageFromWebOperations(this.imgUrl);
}

private static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        return Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("err","poster not found at "+url);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Let me know if more information is needed to answer my question.

Comment: This might not be related but may solve some of your future problems. Have you looked at using an image loading library such as Glide or Picasso?https://github.com/bumptech/glide http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @riggaroo I will look into those libraries. I am relatively new to android development, trying to get my feet wet here but haven't explored external libraries yet.

Comment: Okay, generally trying to do your own image loading and caching can be a nightmare, which is why libraries like those exist.

Comment: any error logs? stacktrace? exceptions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As riggaroo suggests using libraries for these kind of tasks is very useful since they load images asynchronously and manage memory also.

i personally suggest to use Picasso for this kind of task.

you just need to import picasso lib and add this line of code to load image.

```
Picasso.with(this).load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")into(imageView);
```

for importing library and more usage refer [here Picaso Guide](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/picasso-android-tutorial-picasso-image-loader-library/)

Comment: Another great alternative is **[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)** library

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am looking into using the Picasso library to suit my needs. Is there anyway to use this code in a Class that I've created? I'm getting issues with the context portion as it "cannot be referenced from a static context". any ideas?

Comment: you can pass the activity `Context` to the class you created in the constructor or in a method parameter.

Comment: Got it! Just had to change my adapter to use Picasso to load the image into the imageview! Thanks for all your help!